# Why is the variable's value not substituted in the string?

Tags: php, variables, string-substitution

Hai, can anyone help me...
When I write like:

```
$file=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=1932993|twetrg|vsfgsewr');
```

the code gets response as well good.

but when I write like:

```
1. $tk='';
2. $tk='1932993|twetrg|vsfgsewr';//intialize the token value to variable
3. $file=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$tk');
```

then the Line 3. display warning as  "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! "

kindly help me

Answer (score 4):

Variable interpolation does not happen in single quotes.

So use double quotes as:

```
$file=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$tk");
```

Or you can do:

```
$file=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$tk);
```

Comment: As a side note, line 1 in the OP is not necessary.